# Navigation bar item not showing complete

Tags: ios, swift

I can see just this (text should be "item" and it is showing "I...m")

[image]

When I try to add a navigation bar item using the storyboard. Anybody know why? 
This is how I'm adding that button:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Item", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

Comment: is the functionality of this item to go back to the previous view controller ?

Comment: No it is not. It is a special button. It view cannot go back. Also If I add a system button like "Cancel" it shows in the same way that Item.. It seems that the bat button width is too short. But I cannot see how to update it. @WilliamKinaan

Comment: just set the size of the UIBarButtonItem, make the width like 50 or 60 pixels

Comment: I tried that too. But I don't know why it doesn't change @MSU_Bulldog

Answer (score 1):

Put a UIButton as the customView of the UIBarButton to set a custom width of the UIBarButton.

```
// create the nav bar back button
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 24)];
[backButton setTitle:@"Item" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```